# WPF: load ComboBox items from style/resource

Tags: wpf

I have several comboboxes with the same items. I want to put items into `app.xaml`, to prevent code duplication. Can I do something like this?

```
<Style x:Key="MyCombo" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Items">
        <ComboboxItem Content="item one" />
        <ComboboxItem Content="item two" />
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a `Style` that sets the `ItemsSource` property to a collection:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="MyCombo" xmlns:c="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource">
        <Setter.Value>
            <c:ArrayList>
                <ComboBoxItem>item one</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>item two</ComboBoxItem>
            </c:ArrayList>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You could also define a `ComboBox` instance as a resource:

```
<ComboBox x:Key="MyCombo" x:Shared="False">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="item one" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="item two" />
</ComboBox>
```

And use it like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MyCombo}" />
```

A third option would be to create a custom `ComboBox` control that adds the common `ComboBoxItem`s:

```
public class MyCombo : ComboBox
{
    public MyCombo()
    {
        Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Content = "item one" });
        Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Content = "item two" });
    }
}
```

And create an instance of this one:

```
<local:MyCombo />
```

Comment: First one look pretty neat, but I can't override properties, when using `ContentControl`. For example, I have to bind `SelectedValue` to different properties.

Comment: Please see my edited answer. You could set the ItemsSource property to a collection.

Comment: Thanks @mm8, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I used the first method (Style with ItemSource) I just wanted to mention that this looks fine at first but I had some major issues with multiple ComboBox controls using the same style (some of them just wouldn't open anymore and I had errors in the console log). And the problem is that instead of filling the array with ComboBoxItem controls you should fill it with a different type like string. This fixed my problems and it works fine now even with multipe ComboBox controls.